# Cancel service call in Dojo

Tags: web-services, dojo

I want to know if it is possible to cancel a call to a webservice using Dojo. My problem is, e.g., that the user has many elementes to select in a map, and every time he clicks on one of them a call to a webservice is excuted to bring an important volume of data. This operation takes a few seconds of latency. Imagine that user clicks on five elements almost simultaneously: there will be a selected element (the last clicked), but the info panel will be refreshing periodically with the info of the previous elements clicked until the last element info is loaded.

What I want is to cancel all the previous calls (if it possible) and only allow to complete to the last one. I'm working with Dojo. I've seen the documentation but I haven't seen anything useful. Something like the "ajax.abort()" method is what I would expect to find.

I have also thought to create a class to manage the calls and add to a queue every call to a same url in order to only let the last call to render the data, but by this way I still would to wait to complete every service call and then discard the results. I think that the proper way to proceed is to cancel the old calls.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to try and implement something like debouncing (http://unscriptable.com/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/) so that less aborted service calls occur.

Comment: @BuffaloBuffalo thanks for the reply! The solution I proposed doesn't work well because there are some calls that execute their life cycle before I have managed them. I've read the link about the "debounce" function and after a little adaptation to my needs it seems to work fine! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After search in some forums and pages, I've found this one: [www.mike-griffith.com - Cancel dojo XHR in progress](http://www.mike-griffith.com/blog/2008/09/cancel-dojo-xhr-in-progress/). This is exactly what I was looking for (although in the web example is used to "GET" services, the "cancel()" method also works for "POST" calls).

So I will combine the service calls manager with this code to cancel calls with the same url. I also have to manage how to avoid (if I am able to) the raised error when a call is canceled, but this is other task and much less priority.